# return reference to class variable - C++

Tags: c++, reference

So, I have a class `World` where there is a vector of instances of the class `Object`. Now, I'm trying to create a function into World that returns a reference to one of the objects of the vector, so in `main()` you can directly change values into the array. It would be something like:

```
class Object{
   //things
}

class World{
   private:
   vector <Object> ObjectsInWorld;

   public:
   Object functionThatReturnsReference(int index){
      //somehow return reference to ObjectsInWorld[index];
   }
}


int main(){
   World world;
   Object& obj = world.functionThatReturnsReference(2);
   //now changes made to obj should apply also to world's ObjectsInWorld[2]

   return 0;
}
```

Is this possible and legal in C++?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course. Just return an actual reference (it's a value in your code here).

Comment: Yes, it's legal. But you don't return a reference.

Comment: The function could of course legally return an `Object&`, not that this is such a good idea. As soon as you make changes to the vector, the reference might become invalid. Why cannot the code (in main) that makes changes be a member of `World` or of `Object`?

Comment: _"somehow return reference"_ It's just as easy as... actually adding a reference qualifier to the return type. I don't mean to be rude, but do you have a C++ book or tutorial to refer to? It should explain this quite early on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object& World::functionThatReturnsReference(int index)
{
   /// throws an exception if index is out-of-range
   return ObjectsInWorld.at(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define your function to return a reference (note the `&`):

```
 Object& functionThatReturnsReference (int index)
```

*BUT* think at least once more before you do this. Unless your object is a pure container type you don't generally want people messing with your internal state as your invariants can get violated without the user realizing it.